# Sum involving squares of binomial coefficients

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of $\sum_{r=1}^{n}r(^nC_r)^2$.

I am attempting it as follows
$(1+x)^n=C_0+xC_1+x^2C_2+x^3C_3+⋯+x^nC_n$. 
On differentiating we get following relation 
$n(1+x)^{n−1}=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r−1}C_r$. 
Then multiply both sides by $x$. We get $nx(1+x)^{n−1}=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^rC_r$. Now I am considering multiplication of $(1+x)^n$ on both sides, and finding the sum of coefficients of $x^2,x^4,x^6,…,x^{2n}$ on the RHS.

Comment: It will be useful to show your attempt. Else this will get downvoted or closed quickly.

Comment: my approach is as follows $(1+x)^n=C_0+xC_1+x^2C_2+x^3C_3+\cdots+x^nC_n$. On differentiating we get following relation $n(1+x)^(n-1)=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^{r-1}C_r$. Then multiply both sides by $x$. We get $nx(1+x)^{n-1}=\sum_{r=1}^n rx^rC_r$. Now i am considering multiplication of $(1+x)^n$ on both sides, and find sum 
of coefficients of $x^2, x^4, x^6,\dots,x^{2n}$ on the RHS.

Comment: I should edit your question and add your effort to it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos What possible editing can be done to obtain the result.

Comment: If you don't edit your question soon, adding to it your effort, it will be closed.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{r = 1}^{n}r\pars{^{n}C_{r}}^{2} & =
\sum_{r = 0}^{n}r{n \choose r}{n \choose n - r} =
\sum_{r = 0}^{n}r{n \choose r}\bracks{z^{n - r}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}
\sum_{r = 0}^{n}{n \choose r}r\, z^{r} =
\bracks{z^{n}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\ z\,\partiald{}{z}
\sum_{r = 0}^{n}{n \choose r}z^{r}
\\[5mm] & =
\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{n}\,\partiald{\pars{1 + z}^{n}}{z} =
n\bracks{z^{n - 1}}\pars{1 + z}^{2n - 1}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{n{2n - 1 \choose n - 1}}
\end{align}

Comment: @ Felix Thanks for your effort, it would be very helpful if you can explain how you got $z^{n-r}(1+z)^n$ in place of $^nC_{n-r}$.

Comment: @MRizvi $\displaystyle\left[z^{m}\right]\mathrm{f}\left(z\right)$ is a notation for the coefficient of $\displaystyle z^{m}$ in the power expansion of $\displaystyle\mathrm{f}\left(z\right)$. Note that $\displaystyle{n \choose n - r} = {n \choose r}$ is the coeficient of $\displaystyle z^{n - r}$ in the power expansion of $\displaystyle\left(1 + z\right)^{n}$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, Are you completely sure of the third step correctness?